# Python Flask can't access app inside Blueprint

Tags: python, flask, keycloak

I've been trying to build a keycloak oidc authentication flow with flask.

Before using oidc, I need to initialize the oidc variable inside my /auth blueprint.
I can't get it running.

```
from flask import Blueprint, current_app
from flask_oidc import OpenIDConnect

auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__, static_folder="static", template_folder="templates")

app = current_app._get_current_object()

with app.app_context():
    oidc = OpenIDConnect(app)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
```

What can I do to use the OpenIDConnect inside the Blueprint?
I know similar questions have already been asked multiple times but I can't get it running with their solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Flask app factory pattern, i would recommend initializing `Flask-OIDC` using `init_app` method.

Some example code:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_oidc import OpenIDConnect

oidc = OpenIDConnect()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # Initialize OIDC
    oidc.init_app(app)

    return app
```

Now, you can import `oidc` from your application if you need to access the instance, for example `from app import oidc`.

https://flask-oidc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_oidc.OpenIDConnect.init_app